# Uneven borderRadius in ClipRrect - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a wallpaper app, where I used a column and wrap with ClipRrect so that I can get to images in one row, but when I use the borderRadius property in ClipRrect it only works on some images(though they are uneven), and on other images it dosen't work.

```
SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: top2Wall[i]['attributes']['src'],
                            height: 325,
                            width: 188),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

[image: output of my app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of Image size in Widget. Radius applied but because of Image width it will not affect image border radius.

Solution : You need to give boxfit value as below. So, that it will cover full size of widget.

```
 fit : BoxFit.cover
```

Full code :

```
SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: top2Wall[i]['attributes']['src'],
                            fit : BoxFit.cover,
                            height: 325,
                            width: 188),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fit: BoxFit.cover,` on `CachedNetworkImage`

```dart
 CachedNetworkImage(
        
          height: 325,
          width: 188,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
```

I will suggest using `GridView`

```dart
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
    crossAxisSpacing: 9,
    childAspectRatio: 188 / 325, // play with it
  ),
  itemCount: top2Wall.le,//
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: "",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
fit: BoxFit.Cover
```

in `CachedNetworkImage`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).