# how to avoid Space in ClipRrect - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create wallpaper app, But instead of GridView I used wrap as it was easy for me to understand, But on using it there are spaces in between the wallpapers

```
SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: top2Wall[i]['attributes']['src'],
                            width: 188),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Please refer to the image if you cant understand.

[image: Output Image]

Comment: I think you are asking the same question, You can check the answer on your last question

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73453905/10157127) answer your question

Comment: Bro I tried using the gridView as you adviced but it didn't quite worked and made it complicated I just simple removed the hieght property so it took default hieght of the image fetched, so I really don't want to use gridView and also the output was quite opposite from what I expected

Comment: The image height depends on aspect ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to deal with this using GridView as I’ve showed on [last question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73453929/10157127)

```dart
 child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: top2Wall[i]['attributes']['src'],
      width: 188, 
      height: X. your fixed image height,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

And for spacing use

```dart
  child: Wrap(
          spacing: 12,
          runSpacing: 12,
```

Comment: I appreciate it but could you please tell me If I can perfrom the action without using Gridview.builder

Comment: yes, you can use `spacing` and `runSpacing`. Also provide the height and fit property